# text file attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, template

I would like to have text files with text for each of the brands i carry

i am using this to call the brand logo and link to brand page

```
<?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand');
echo strtolower('<a href="/shop-by-brand/'.str_replace(' ', '-',$brand).'.html" alt="'.$brand.'">') ;
echo '<img src="/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.jpg" alt="'.$brand.'">' ?></a>
```

so the question is would this work im getting a red line flag in dreamweaver

```
<?php 
$brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand'); 
$file = fopen("/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_rep‌​lace(' ', '_',$brand).'.txt" alt="'.$brand.'"); 
?>
```

open to any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a red line flag because you're not using `fopen` properly.

From the official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php :

> fopen — Opens file or URL

In your case you don't need to open the image as the web browser will display it by reading your HTML code.

The only improvement I see in your code would be some formatting to make it easier to read:

```
<?php 
    $brand = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
    $link = strtolower("/shop-by-brand/" . str_replace(' ', '-',$brand) . ".html");
    $img = "/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/" . str_replace(' ', '_', $brand) . ".jpg";
?>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $brand; ?>" />
</a>
```

Note: the anchor tag `<a>` does not support any `alt` attribute, I've replaced it with the global `title` attribute in the code above.

Comment: so this qwont fetch text from a file ?  <?php 
$brand=$_product->getAttributeText('brand'); 
$file = fopen("/skin/frontend/default/default/images/media/'.str_rep‌​lace(' ', '_',$brand).'.txt" alt="'.$brand.'"); 
?>

Comment: @user3677211 it could but why would you want to do that as you're already storing the brand in an attribute ?

Comment: I want to add some text in a file that is easily modified by staff  a short brand description excerpt

Comment: @user3677211 why not creating a brand description attribute ?